# How do you call this type of process/diagram style?

Tags: diagram, bpmn

[image]
does the above diagram style has a specific name, if yes, would you recommend a software (preferably an web app) to create them (We have a lucidchart account but we couldn't find this template, though)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML they're generally referred to as sequence diagrams. Any UML editor should let you create them, including LucidChart.

Comment: Thanks, I found it now in Lucid. although, it's not as good-looking as the one I do in... powerpoint! 
LOL. Cheers